# Jquery check if a div(several divs with same class) contains a div with class on

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have three divs with class UserDetail. if a div doesnot contain `div.info` then have to hide that `div.UserDetail`

Update from comment:

I have tried this:

```
var childInfo=$('div.UserDetail').find("div.info").size(); 
if(childInfo==0) $('div.UserDetail').hide();
```

This is not working as all the divs contains same class name and other two divs have the child div `class=info`

Comment: HTML? Sample code you have tried?

Comment: I have tried as 
var childInfo=$('div.UserDetail').find("div.info").size();
if(childInfo==0)
    $('div.UserDetail').hide();

This is not as all the divs contains same class name and other two divs ha the child div class=info.

Comment: Answer added (using only a jQuery selector below).

Answer (score 1):

Use `:has` with `:not` selector:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5pbap/

```
$('.UserDetail:not(:has(.info))').hide()
```

or in full (if you care about the divs): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5pbap/1/

```
$('div.UserDetail:not(:has(div.info))').hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work

```
$.each($('div.UserDetail'), function(i, value){
     if($(value).find('div.info').length == 0)  
        {
          $(value).hide();            
        }
});
```

Comment: This does work (although it can be simplified a bit). Using `filter` would have made it simpler again, but it can be done just using jQuery `:not` & `:has` selectors.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie true and i liked you precise snippet. Thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: +1 for getting it working first time anyway (all the other `each` answers got the logic wrong).

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdLjS/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="userDetails">1</div>
<div class="userDetails">2<div class="info"></div></div>
<div class="userDetails">3</div>
```

**JS**

```
$.each( $( "div.userDetails" ), function( i, div ) {
    if ( $( div ).find( "div.info" ).length == 0 ) {
        $( div ).hide();
    }
} );
```

Comment: You have the logic reversed. it needs to hide any divs that *do not* contain the child div. Your example should only show div `2`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".UserDetail").each(function (index) {
        if ( $(this).find('div.info').length < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This one does not work at all: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5pbap/2/ (ah, you have a typo `length` too - still does not work though)

Comment: still does not work though as `length` is not a function

Comment: Sorry, too quick with the ()

Comment: Now you just need to reverse the logic and you are done :) It should *only* show the div with the matching child div.

Comment: -1: Certainly has been a long day, but still wrong after 4 attempts (and JSFiddles available to check it) you should have been able to get this working with all the hints. Sorry :(